# What causes this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: scala, runtime-error

I am new to scala.

here is simple code

---

```
object SimpleIfStatementDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {   
    var numA: Int = args(0).toInt
    var numB: Int = args(1).toInt
    if(numA>numB) {
      print(numA)
    } else {
      print(numB)               
    }
  }
}
```

---

it's can be compile,but can not be run it. here is error i got it

---

> ```
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0   at
> ```
>
> Main$.main(SimpleIfSatementDemo.scala:5)  at
>   Main.main(SimpleIfSatementDemo.scala)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:33)     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:40)  at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.scala$tools$nsc$ScriptRunner$$runCompiled(ScriptRunner.scala:171)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ScriptRunner.scala:157)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.waitingForThreads(package.scala:26)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.withCompiledScript(ScriptRunner.scala:130)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:188)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:201)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:58)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)

---

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program is not being passed enough arguments (it requires at least two; see [the java command manual](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) for how these can be specified). Consider putting this code as the first line of the main method:

```
println("I have " + args.length + " argument(s)")
```

And then try this on the Scala REPL to see a similar explosion:

```
val a = Array("Hello world!") // array of one element
a(0)      // access first element, okay
a(1)      // access second element -- KABOOM!
```

How can this new knowledge be used to make the program more robust (and not throw the exception)?

Happy coding.

---

The article [First Steps to Scala](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/steps.html) has examples of passing and using arguments.

Comment: thanks mate, but i try the my code on windows and works fine , i dont know why is not working in the mac os x. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you run at the command line with 2.9.0 or later and that your source code is contained in a file called `SimpleIfStatementDemo.scala`:

```
$ scala SimpleIfStatementDemo.scala 1 2
```

will provide the arguments 1 and 2 to your program.

On 2.9.x and 2.8.x, you can also compile the source into `class` files compiled into an intermediate byte code for the JVM. A good practice is to have them under a subdirectory (`classes` in this example):

```
$ scalac -d classes SimpleIfStatementDemo.scala
$ scala -cp classes SimpleIfStatementDemo 1 2
```

If you run within an IDE, you have to figure out how to edit the *run* configuration to add arguments to the run command.